# parse template tag to XML in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-database

I am trying to print get some value from database and print into xml dynamically.

This is my model:

```
class Somemodel(models.Model):
    Party_Id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Label = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Party_Id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

This is my view function

```
def xmlcontent(request):
  obj = Somemodel.objects.get(pk=1)
  obj.Party_Id = obj.pk
  pprint.pprint(obj.DDEX_Party_Id)
  return render(request, "content.xml", {"DDID": "obj"},
content_type =   "application/xhtml+xml")
```

My content.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><br/>
<</MessageHeader>MessageHeader><br/>
    {% for i in DDID %}<br/>
        {{ i.pk }}<br/>
    {% endfor %} <br/>
<</MessageHeader>/MessageHeader><br/>
```

Its suppose to print Party_id but not printing.. Am i miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems:

1. You are sending the string `"obj"` instead of the object `obj` in your context dictionary.
2. In your xml template, you have a loop, but the context variable `DDID` is going to be a single object, not a collection or queryset, because you are using `.get`.
3. You have extra `<` in your XML, and XML does not include `<br />` tags. The resulting file will be invalid.

To save yourself some trouble, just use the built-in [`serializers`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/serialization/). The first example shows you how to export XML:

```
from django.core import serializers

def some_method(request):
    XMLSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("xml")
    xml_serializer = XMLSerializer()
    xml_serializer.serialize(SomeModel.objects.filter(pk=1).values('id'), stream=request)
```

Comment: for intent only i give <br/> tag . I changed into obj gives nothing. You mentioned serializer i tried but using that i can able to get all the database into xml format. But i need particular value from db to print. I don`t have much exp to use serializer to get what i need this point

Answer (score 0):

With this line

```
return render(request, "content.xml", {"DDID": "obj"},
```

you are passing string `"obj"` to template rather than the `obj` object. Update it to

```
return render(request, "content.xml", {"DDID": obj},
```

Also `obj` is not a list but single object, so you cannot use `{%for i in DDID %} ...`

Comment: I changed into {{ pk }} . Thats gives me no output

Comment: @rajasimon You need to do `{{DDID.pk}}`.

Comment: Changed inot {{ DDID }} give value 1 but i know that`s not correct. And then i changed this line into  obj = Somemodel.objects.get(Party_Id).. Gives Exceptn 'too many values to unpack'

Comment: pprint.pprint(obj) gives this output ([{'Party_Id': u'112'}],) but i need that value come into xml ...?